# MySQL: INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains UserId & his Friends Id like:

```
----------------------------------------------
UserFriendsId    |    UserId    |    FriendId
----------------------------------------------
     1                  1              2
----------------------------------------------
     2                  1              3
----------------------------------------------
     3                  2              1
----------------------------------------------
     4                  2              3
----------------------------------------------
```

This table data shows that User-1 & User-2 are friend & they also have frndship with User-3.
Now I want to find common friend(s) among UserId 1 & UserId 2 for eg:
In sentance my query is: User 1 & User 2 have 1 common Friend FriendId 3.

For this I used SQL query for INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.* 
  FROM userfriends t1 
 INNER JOIN userfriends t2 
    ON t1.FriendId = t2.FriendId 
 WHERE t1.UserId = 2
```

But not return required result..

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
  from MyTable as A
 inner join MyTable as B 
    on     (A.UserID = 1 and B.UserID = 2)
       and (A.FriendID = B.FriendID)
```

edited

Answer (score 0):

Try this query (very similar to th others posted)

```
SELECT t1.UserID,T2.userID,T1.FriendID 
  FROM userfriends t1 
  JOIN userfriends t2 
    ON     (t1.FriendId = t2.FriendId )
       and (T1.userID <>T2.userID)
 WHERE t1.UserId = 2 
   and T2.userId=1
```

Beware that this reports every friendship-chain twice once you remove the absolute IDs. To avoid that I ask that T1.UserID be smaller than T2.userID:

```
SELECT t1.UserID,T2.userID,T1.FriendID 
  FROM userfriends t1 
  JOIN userfriends t2 
    ON     (t1.FriendId = t2.FriendId )
       and (T1.userID < T2.userID)
```

Comment: How do you think it will report twice?
Check these clause `t1.UserId = 2 and T2.userId=1`.
Then checking `(T1.userID < T2.userID)` or `(T1.userID <>T2.userID)` are useless.

Comment: @Sujee: BANG (hand hit's head.) **You are right** I was thinking too much bout the general case! My appologies!

Comment: No problem @lexu. Sometimes this happens to me too!

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT table1.name, table2.salary
  FROM employee AS table1 INNER JOIN info AS table2 ON table1.name = table2.name;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
select u1.FriendId
from userfriends u1
inner join userfriends u2 on u1.FriendId = u2.FriendId
where u1.UserId = 1 and u2.UserId = 2
```

Comment: @Sujee: See my answer to your comment below my reply .. I'm removing the down-vote.